# Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: apache). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:

Tags: ssl-certificate, free, lets-encrypt, certbot

here is my subdomain : http://django.arifsultani291.digital.

here is the error details :

Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: apache). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
Domain: django.arifsultani291.digital
Type:   unauthorized
Detail: 2a02:4780:3:721:0:391e:fb8f:1: Invalid response from http://django.arifsultani291.digital/.well-known/acme-challenge/ZjK_8CZtjYX1zFYlCkmkKb_SL36-IvGdmxsvGWYSNvk: 404

Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to verify the temporary Apache configuration changes made by Certbot. Ensure that the listed domains point to this Apache server and that it is accessible from the internet.

Some challenges have failed.
Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.

the subdomain is pointed to the digitalocean droplet, but it is showing error  when i want to add letsencrypt ssl.

i tried multipul ways to solve this error but i couldn't